# ASP.Net Load Test -- what do these values mean?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I am testing how many requests my web server can respond to, and I'm using a Test project in VS 2010, using a LoadTest running 1 single actual test method.  I'm getting results, but I'm not sure what they mean.  In the graph below, "Test Response Time", I'm not sure what scale these numbers are from.  Any have the legend available?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Test Response Time' is the number of milliseconds it took to run one test. You can find more detailed info (including units) in the view just below the graphs.